# FirebaseList - Unable to access parse data fetched from firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm getting " Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' " when running the following code.

html template:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">
      <ion-item>
        {{ item.$value }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button color="danger" icon-only (click)="removeItem(item.$key)"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

page ts:

```
shoppingItems: AngularFireList<any>;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider) {
    this.shoppingItems = this.firebaseProvider.getShoppingItems();
}
```

firebase provider

```
  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello FirebaseProvider Provider');
    console.log("Shopping items"+afd.list('/shoppingItems/'))
  }

  getShoppingItems() {

    console.log("Shopping items"+this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/'))
    return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/');
  }
  addItem(name) {
    this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').push(name);
  }
```

firebase db

```
shoppingItems
 -KxmiUt64GJsPT84LQsI: "qwerty"
 -KxmifqyfD41tRPwFh07: "key"
```

From the web app I was able to add items to firebase db. But I wasn't able to render the data from firebase. I am getting the above mentioned error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045479/integrating-firebase-with-ionic-3-and-angular..

Comment: @SurajRao yes, I am also following the same tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## AngularFire2 V5

`this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/')` does not return an asynchronous observable which is supposed to work with `async` pipe. It returns a reference to the List in the real-time database.
You need to use `valueChanges()` to return that.

In your provider return the observable,

```
 getShoppingItems() {

    console.log("Shopping items"+this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/'))
    return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').valueChanges();//here
  }
```

***If you are accessing through `$key/$value`***,
Check the [upgrade details for angularfire2 v4 to 5](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#moving-away-from-key-and-value). This is because `FirebaseList` is deprecated and `AngularFireList` is now returned from version 5.

> Calling .valueChanges() returns an Observable without any metadata. If you are already persisting the key as a property then you are fine. However, if you are relying on $key, then you need to use .snapshotChanges()

You need to use `snapshotChanges()`

```
 getShoppingItems() {

    console.log("Shopping items"+this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/'))
    return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').snapshotChanges();//here
  }
```

**To access `$key` or `$value` in html,
use `item.payload.key` and `item.payload.val()`**

Comment: this return value should be assigned to a variable of type Angularfirelist[] right?, how to do that in page ts?

Comment: from your example, you are already using `async` so you want to assign observable of list(which you are already doing). If you want data, you will have to subscribe in component

Comment: Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: I am still unable to get the value's using item.$value in template. any idea on how to debug / solve it?

Comment: oh hold on you are using AngularFire2 version 5 ? the tutorial seems to be using older version

Comment: I checked the link and used snapshotChanges method. Still, the template renders no of entries correctly in UI. But below is not the way to access the content i guess(i.e. item.$value in template.)

Comment: try `item.payload.val()`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @SurajRao  I am a bit confused. it already returns FirebaseListObservable, why make it observable again? I just added ionViewDidLoad and it worked fine. I didn't change providers.

Comment: That is from version 5 of angularfire2 @ImdadAli you must be using 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Add `ionViewDidLoad` life cycle in the `home.ts` file and instead of constructor load your item in `ionViewDidLoad` , replace your constructor with below code

```
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.shoppingItems = this.firebaseProvider.getShoppingItems();
    console.log(this.shoppingItems);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Import at page.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
 import { ShoppingItem } from '../../model/shoppingitem';
```

import your provider the right way from your provider

```
 import { FirebaseProvider } from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';

 export class Page {

  shoppingItems:Observable<ShoppingItem[]>;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
             public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider) {

                this.shoppingItems=this.firebaseProvider
                .getShoppingItem()
                .snapshotChanges()
                .map(
                  changes=>{
                    return changes.map(c=>({
                      key:c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val(),
                    }));
                  }
                );
          }
        }

     }
```

firebaseProvider

note the `'shopping-list'` is the table at the firebase database

```
  private itemListRef = this.afDatabase.list<ShoppingItem>('shopping-list');

  constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

 .getShoppingItem(){

   return this.itemListRef;

  }
 }
```

Your shoppingitem model

```
 export interface ShoppingItem{
  key?:string;
  }
```