# Reading data from firebase in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I want read data from firebase database with ionic 3

I'm using this code but it's giving me error `property subscribe does not exist on type AngularFireObject`

```
this.db.object('/incident').subscribe(data => {

this.items = data;

  })
```

Meanwhile I was able to send data to the firebase using the following code

```
sendIncident(){

this.db.list('/incident').push({
    title: this.title.value,
    detail: this.detail.value
})
 }
```

I will appreciate any idea on how to overcome this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseList - Unable to access parse data fetched from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048556/firebaselist-unable-to-access-parse-data-fetched-from-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using ionic but angular with angularfire, but this should work for you

```
this.items = this.db.object('/incident').valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something like this:

```
this.subscription = this.db.list('/notes').valueChanges().subscribe(data =>{
 })
```