# Display AngularFireList data on HTML gets me an error

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm trying to display the data retrieved from my firebase on Home.html, but I keep getting the same error over and over:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Can you help me?

I have the following code on my application:

user.service.ts

```
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database/interfaces';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class UserService {

  users: AngularFireList<User[]>;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public af: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.users = this.af.list('users');
  }

  create(user: User): void {
    this.af.list('users').push(user);
  }
}
```

home.ts

```
import { UserService } from './../../providers/user/user.service';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database/interfaces';

export class HomePage {

  users: AngularFireList<User[]>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public userService: UserService
  ) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.users = this.userService.users;
  }
```

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list no-lines>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
      {{ user.name }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button block (click)="onSignUp()">Sign Up</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: what does console.log(this.users) shows?

Comment: {query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ, …}
auditTrail
:
ƒ (events)
push
:
ƒ (data)
query
:
Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
remove
:
ƒ remove(item)
set
:
ƒ dataOperation(item, value)
snapshotChanges
:
ƒ (events)
stateChanges
:
ƒ (events)
update
:
ƒ dataOperation(item, value)
valueChanges
:
ƒ (events)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseList - Unable to access parse data fetched from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048556/firebaselist-unable-to-access-parse-data-fetched-from-firebase)

Comment: I reverted your last edit because questions are for questions and answers for answers. Everyone can see the answer in your accepted answer :) And because you accepted it people can see this question is solved.

Comment: @AndréKool okay! Tksss and my mistake for the wrong use :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with making a mistake sometimes. This is a complex site. Just make sure you learn from your mistakes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: 2018-08-06

This have solved my problem:

On my user.service.ts I've declared my vars like this:

```
usersRef: AngularFireList<any>;
users: Observable<any[]>;
```

And in the constructor:

```
this.usersRef = this.af.list('users');
this.users = this.usersRef.valueChanges();
this.users.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

This way I'm able to recover the values from 'users' on my HTML like this:

```
<ion-list no-lines>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of users | async">
      {{ user.name }}
    </button>
</ion-list>
```

And in home.ts:

```
users: Observable<any[]>;

ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.users = this.userService.users;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
this.users = this.af.list('users');
```

to that :

```
this.users = this.af.list('users').valueChanges();
```

Comment: By doing that the following error shows up: Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<User[]>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>'.

Comment: Change users : AngularFireList<User[]>  to users : Observable<any[]>

Comment: Same error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'...

Comment: try : this.af.list('users').valueChanges().subscribe(users => {console.log(users)});

Comment: Error: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'. 
And if I change my users to users: AngularFireList<User[]>; again I get: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<User[]>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'Subscription'.